# What should I pass as third parameter in curl_easy_setopt when using ofstream?

Tags: c++, file-io, libcurl, ofstream

This is working okay

```
FILE *outfile = fopen(resultPath.c_str(), "w");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, outfile);
```

But I did not want to use fopen() as I used ofstream in rest of the code.
So I tried this :

```
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open(resultPath.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, outfile.beg);
```

I am not sure if the third parameter is correct, no errors are shown while compiling, but the program crashes while writing.
So what is the correct way to do this ?

Comment: Unfortunately(?) there is no way to get a `FILE*` out from a `std::[io]fstream`. The correct way is to use `fopen`.

Comment: @BoBTFish Thank you, I was kind of feeling guilty using fopen() after seeing anti - fopen() posts here. Now I feel better.

Comment: Yup, it sucks, but you are using a c library. For what it's worth, it seems there is a c++ API, but it doesn't look like much is going on there: http://code.google.com/p/curlpp/

Comment: oh, libcurl is a c library, I was unaware if this, thanks for the info.

Comment: Was the fact that it's stylised as `cURL` (c library for URLs) not a clue :)

Comment: Yes, I thought about it that way, but was not sure

Answer (score 0):

> That parameter can be a long, a function pointer, an object pointer or
>   a curl_off_t, depending on what the specific option expects.

Comment: Yes, and "If you don't use a callback, you must pass a '`FILE *`' (cast to '`void *`')". How is this supposed to help?

Answer (score 0):

The argument given for this function is related to the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`. The `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` takes parameters like this `size_t function( char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);`

So, if we assume you have a writefunction roughly like this:

```
size_t write_data( char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);
{
    ofstream& outstream = ???; 
    ... 
    outstream.write(ptr, size * nmemb);
    ... 
}
```

then the `userdata` should be something you can create an `ofstream&` from.

I would pass the address of `outfile`.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &outfile);
```

and then the write_data function becomes this:

```
size_t write_data( char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata);
{
    ofstream& outstream = *reinterpret_cast<ofstream*>(userdata); 
    ... 
    outstream.write(ptr, size * nmemb);
    ... 
}
```

Reference: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html

Comment: I am not using an callback function. Then also I tried using &outfile, but it crashed then too.

Comment: Ehm, if you don't provide your own writedata function, you can't pass anything other than a `FILE *`. The default function would do something like`return fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *)userdata);` - so if you pass anything other than NULL or a valid `FILE *`, it's going to use whatever you pass as if it was a `FILE *` - which is unlikely to work at all.

Comment: thanks, That verifies BoBTFish's comment, Now I feel comfortable using fopen()

Comment: Or you could flesh out my code above (should work fine to just take out the `...` bits, and add a bit of error checking, and return the number of items written (size) if all checks out OK. That would save having to include `cstdio` and using `FILE *`/`fopen()`.